# Order UITableView cells by calculated distance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform

I'm quite new to iOS development. And I got stuck with a problem.

I want to order my `UITableView` Descending by Distance on my custom tableview.
I get the date by a query on my parse.com databse.
Then, when creating the cell, I calculate the distance between my current location and the geopoint location from the database object. --> That works fine!

But how do I order the TableView descending/ascending by the calculated distance?

Here is my code, where I create the cell and calculate the distance:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath object:(PFObject *)object
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"stationCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    } 
    // Configure the cell
    PFFile *thumbnail = [object objectForKey:@"img"];
    PFImageView *thumbnailImageView = (PFImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    thumbnailImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.jpg"];
    thumbnailImageView.file = thumbnail;
    [thumbnailImageView loadInBackground];

    UILabel *nameLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:101];
    nameLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"name"];

    UILabel *adressLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:102];
    adressLabel.text = [object objectForKey:@"adress"];

    // DISTANCE Calculation

    [PFGeoPoint geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground:^(PFGeoPoint *currentLocationGeoPoint, NSError *error) { //Get current Location
        if (!error) {

            PFGeoPoint *distanceGeoPoint = [object objectForKey:@"location"];

            double distanceDouble  = [currentLocationGeoPoint distanceInKilometersTo:distanceGeoPoint];
            NSLog(@"Distance: %.1f",distanceDouble); // %.1f - limits to 1.1

            UILabel *distanceLabel = (UILabel*) [cell viewWithTag:103];
            distanceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", distanceDouble];

        }
    }];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Wain!
I separated the MVC and the view update.
Then I changed the initial query and used the following function to order the result by distance:

```
[query whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:userGeoPoint];
```

http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKey:nearGeoPoint:

Answer (score 0):

In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` it is too late to sort the rows, that method is called when
cells are about to be *displayed*.

You should sort the elements after fetching them, and use the sorted array as table view data source.

Answer (score 0):

Separate your Model data (MVC) from your view update (the code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`). i.e. don't call `geoPointForCurrentLocationInBackground` from `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. Do it once and get all of the location data.

Now, you should have an array of your location data. In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can get data out of that array using the `indexPath`.

When you want to change the order of the results, reverse the array. (often done with a `reverseObjectEnumerator`).